# Jest & React Router: Testing component containing various routes - testing to see if specific component is rendered based on route?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-router, jestjs, enzyme

**Component structure:**

Routes component and the test file are show below.

The code gives me a pass when I run test, but it should fail no? Because I have "/loginasf" as

initialEntries. What I am trying to achieve is depending on route I want the test to pass when the right component is rendered.

```js
describe("clientroutes renders loginform", () => {
  it("Routes contains LoginForm", () => {
    const wrapper = mount(
        <MemoryRouter initialEntries={["/loginasf"]} initialIndex={0}>
          <ClientRoutes />
        </MemoryRouter>
      );
    expect(wrapper.find(LoginForm).length).toBe(1);
  });
});
```

```js
export default () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route path={["/login", "/"]} exact component={LoginForm} />
        <Route path={["/forgotpassword"]} exact component={ForgotPassword} />
        <Route path={["/uploadmain"]} exact component={UploadMain} />

        {/* Finally, catch all unmatched routes */}
        <Route path="*" component={About} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
};
```

Comment: I recently did this using the React Testing Library: https://github.com/cmacdonnacha/react-boilerplate/tree/master/src/App.test.tsx

Comment: You could also check the url route, see the second test here https://github.com/cmacdonnacha/react-boilerplate/tree/master/src/components/Sidebar.test.tsx